# Create IJobExecutionContext object

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

How to create IJobExecutionContext class instance for testing purposes? Like

```
IJobExecutionContext context = new ... ???
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Moq. https://github.com/Moq/moq4

```
var mockJobExecutionContext= new Mock<IJobExecutionContext>();
mockJobExecutionContext.Setup(
   // ... do method setup here
);
mockJobExecutionContext.SetupProperty(x=>x.JobInstance);
var jobExecutionContext = mockJobExecutionContext.Object;
```

Good quickstart here: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: Moq? Yes, its a mocking framework that saves you time and "space" on creating your mock dependencies. You mentioned in your question that you are attempting to test the IJobExecutionContext. I assume this means it is a dependency for one of your classes.

You would not, however, add the Moq dependency in your class library. You would only need the reference in your integration or unit test assemblies.

Comment: How are you assigning a `Mock<IJobExecutionContext>()` to a `IJobExecutionContext`??!

Comment: Good point. IJobExecutionContext should be 'var'.

Answer (score 0):

JobExecutionContextImpl provides an implementation for IJobExecutionContext. see https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Impl/JobExecutionContextImpl.cs

Not sure if this is what you need for testing

Comment: Not available for use at least in 2.0.x version. Solved by passing only JobDataMap object to my method: context.MergedJobDataMap