# Unit Testing quartz-dot-net (Quartz.Net) Execute function

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I would like to test the Execution function of my Quartz.Net jobs, which implement the Quartz.IJob:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
```

The problem: how to create a new IJobExecutionContext class instance. Or even instead of creating a New one, just get it from an already existing scheduled job.

The goal is to create a test such as:

```
[Test()]
public void Test()
{
    IJobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = ???; //get a defined JobExecutionContext somehow...
    m_myJob.Execute(jobExecutionContext);
}
```

All I have found has been [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502655/create-ijobexecutioncontext-object) with the same problem. All he said was "Solved by passing only JobDataMap object to my method: context.MergedJobDataMap" which I don't seem to be able to reproduce. And the other proposition, the use of Moq, is out of reach for me at this current time. Although if it really is the only way, I will focus on this solution. But I thought it was reasonable if I tried to find a simpler way first.

Comment: Have you classes which implement the interface `IJobExecutionContext`? You can use them.

Comment: No I don't. It is an internal way for Quartz.Net to call the main execution of a job. `IJobExecutionContext` has 17 methods to be implemented. This is why I thought it would be simpler as a test to "crop" an existing one from an already scheduled job. But even that I something don't seem to be able to accomplish.

Comment: If it is suitable for you to use the internal classes of Quartz.Net instead of test doubles, you can use assembly attribute [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

*IJobExecutionContext* is an interface, which means you can create a mock version of it easily. Either by using a Mocking framework, like Moq as you mentioned, or by creating a class just for use in your test

```
private class MockExecutionContext : IJobExecutionContext 
{


}
```

you will need to implement all the members of the interface, and give them the behaviour which your test needs, but the compiler/intellisense will help you with this. Depending on what you are testing, you should be able to give most of the members 'stub' implementations that do nothing other than satisfy the member signatures.

Comment: I gave it a try and it went OK. I had to go twice deeper in terms of class implementation because one of the dependencies, but since I just needed the JobMap, the other 16 function implementation could be left as 'stub' implementations, as you said. I feel like it is not the cleaner solution, but it works for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: @XavierPeña - i realize this was ages ago, but would be cool if you could post that mock implementation